# Why can the argument of `uvm_info not be convert2string()?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm, questasim

I defined a class called `repeat_seq`, which extends from `base_seq`, which extends from `uvm_sequence`. Some slicing code has shown the following:

```
class repeat_seq extends hermes_base_seq;
...
hermes_router_seq_config cfg;
...
task pre_body();
 super.pre_body();
 if(!uvm_config_db #(hermes_router_seq_config)::get(get_sequencer(),"","config",cfg))
   `uvm_fatal(get_type_name(), "config config_db lookup failed")
endtask
task body;
...
`uvm_info("repeat_seq",cfg.convert2string(),UVM_HIGH)
...
endtask: body
```

In class `hermes_router_seq_config`, the `convert2string` function has shown the following:

```
virtual function string convert2string();
  string s = super.convert2string();
  s = { s, $psprintf( "\n port       : %0d", port) };
  s = { s, $psprintf( "\n p_size     : %0d", p_size) };
  s = { s, $psprintf( "\n header     : %H" , header) };
  s = { s, $psprintf( "\n valid_addr : %p" , hermes_pkg::valid_addrs(port)) };
  s = { s, $psprintf( "\n npackets   : %0d", npackets) };
  return s;
endfunction: convert2string
```

However, in the transcript file, the corresponding message is:

```
UVM_INFO /home/ICer/nocc/noc-router/tb/seqs/src/repeat_seq.sv(39) @ 130000: uvm_test_top.env.agent_master_2.sequencer@@seq [repeat_seq]
```

I find that an `` `uvm_info `` doesn't print as  expected in monitor, which also takes `convert2string()` as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of `` `uvm_info `` can be `convert2string()`.

In the transcript file, look at the lines *immediately following* the `UVM_INFO` line.  You didn't show us the code for `super.convert2string`, but after that, the 1st character you assign to the string is a newline (`\n`):

```
s = { s, $psprintf( "\n port       : %0d", port) };
```

This means that the `port` string will be on a different line from the `UVM_INFO` string.  Your code shows 5 newline characters, which means your output will be on 5 different lines in the transcript file.

Your output could look like:

```
UVM_INFO /home/ICer/nocc/noc-router/tb/seqs/src/repeat_seq.sv(39) @ 130000: uvm_test_top.env.agent_master_2.sequencer@@seq [repeat_seq]
 port    : 5
 p_size  : 2
 header  : A
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks again for answering my question.  Funny to say, I used a python script to filter out UVM_INFO line to a new log file so there are no messages I expected in the log file. This is a low level mistake, thanks for your time.